# How can I get a list with all papers that cites one person's papers in the last month?

Tags: publications, research-process, citations, google-scholar, bibliometrics

I want to know **which papers cite papers of author X in the last 30 days or 60 days**. Is such a query possible? I don't know any provider that supports that kind of view on authors' citations.

I can use alerts from Google Scholar to get that information every week. But I want to do this as a search query right now. Semantic Scholar also does not provide this opportunity. Does anybody know a site that supports this query?

How can I acquire this information without using Google Scholar and going in the citation of every paper of the author and sorting them by date or restricting the date range?

Comment: You may want to say why you want this.

Comment: I want the functionality I found on scopus called "Cited by X documents" but is not shown for normal users. But I need this on the data from google scholar. I know there is a highly relevant paper citing a highly productive and highly cited author, so it is not possible to look for this manually. I need this paper. And the citing occured around 30 days ago. Please help me how to get a list of all papers citing the work of this author in the last 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft Academic](https://academic.microsoft.com) provides something close. It creates a profile page for each author, and under the "Cited By" tab, you can see all the papers that cited that author's papers. I do not know how accurate it is in practice, however.

There doesn't seem to be any direct way to filter out citations by the last 30-60 days. But you could still get the information with a little bit of work. In the left pane under the "Cited By" tab, there's a "Filter By" option where you can filter by year. You can then sort the citations by selecting "Sort By Newest First" in the drop-down menu on the right, and then traverse the list for the duration you are interested in. This is not as bad as the case with Google Scholar since you don't need to check for each publication separately, all you need to find is the cutoff point in the dates.

There also seems to be an [API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/academic-knowledge/) to access the data, so you could look into that as well in case it is useful, and it may possibly provide more fine grained access to the data. I haven't tried using it, however.

Screenshot for reference:
[image]

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated to this service in any manner.</sub>

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! Your method works great, but unfourtanetly microsoft academic had crawled 20% less then google scholar in my case. And as you can imagine: my paper was included in this missing 20% ...so if anybody has also a solution on google scholar for future searches, please let me know!